# expressjs: my session expired too early what to do?

Tags: node.js, session, express

This is my code.I can set expired to 2 second and it seem like work. But when it set it to a longer time it not work.

```
//Express session
app.use(session({
  secret:'secret',
  saveUninitialized:true,
  resave:true,
  cookie: { maxAge: 60*10000}           
}));
```

My login session auto logout after 2 minutes. Is there something wrong?

Comment: how much longer time

Comment: try to set false on `resave`

Comment: Not work, any other sugestions